# Convert from string(yyyyMMddHHmmss) to DateTime with SQL Server

Tags: .net, sql-server, vb.net, oracle

I am migrating from Oracle's `to_date` function to SQL Server's `convert` function.

I want to know a good way to convert a string of format `yyyyMMddHHmmss` to `DateTime` type.

I could write a program, but it is too redundant, so I would like to know how to improve it.

```
'Get String Date (yyyyMMddHHmmss)
Dim strNowDate = Strings.Format(Now, "yyyyMMddHHmmss") 'format cannot be changed. (Because, referenced from many)

'some logics...

'Oracle script before migration.
sqlBuf.Append(" ,to_date('" & strNowDate & "', 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')" & vbCrLf)

'SQL Server script after migration.(too redundancy... I want to make it more cool.)
sqlBuf.Append(" ,convert(DATETIME, '" & DateTime.ParseExact(strNowDate, "yyyyMMddHHmmss", Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") & "')" & vbCrLf)
```

Comment: try `convert(datetime, substring(@d,1,4) + '-' + substring(@d,5,2) + '-' + substring(@d,7,2) + ' ' + substring(@d,9,2) + ':' + substring(@d,11,2) + ':' + substring(@d,13,2))`

Comment: Or as variant you can use `STUFF`-function `SELECT CONVERT(datetime,STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(STUFF('20171116115733',5,0,'-'),8,0,'-'),11,0,' '),14,0,':'),17,0,':'),120) -- yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`

Comment: @T.Yanchi - The editor added invisible symbols to my post. You can see '?' if you do the following `SELECT 'CONVERT(datetime,STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(''201711161157‌​33'',5,0,''-''),8,0,''-''‌​),11,0,'' ''),14,0,'':''),17,0,'':''),120)'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ORACLE and SQL Server both are different, I assume its SQL Server.
try this

```
select
convert(datetime,stuff(stuff(stuff('20171116115733', 9, 0, ' '), 12, 0, ':'),
        15, 0, ':')) ConvertedDate
```

there are many possible ways given here

https://rdineshkumar.wordpress.com/tag/how-to-convert-yyyymmddhhmmss-to-datetimedatetime-in-sql-server/

Answer (score 1):

It's my variant from my comment

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime,STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(STUFF('20171116115733',5,0,'-'),8,0,'-'),11,0,' '),14,0,':'),17,0,':'),120) -- yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss
```